# Cakephp how to change the link /app/webroot/blog to /blog

Tags: cakephp

I have a website which was built by CakePHP. I want Blog section to be built with Wordpress so I upload a Wordpress folder to /app/webroot/ folder and rename it to 'blog'. I installed Wordpress normally. In the homepage, I show the link to Blog section with the code

```
<?php echo $this->webroot. '/blog'; ?>
```

I have checked it and it showed '**http//mydomain.com/blog**' but I clicked that link, it automatically redirected to '**http//mydomain.com/app/webroot/blog**'.

I just want the link to be redirected to '**http//mydomain.com/blog**'. How can I do it?

P/S: I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: This isn't the fix but, you don't need the '/blog'. You want 'blog' since $this->webroot already has the trailing slash.

Comment: @Tim Joyce: Oh, I forget to remove the trailing slash. Thank you for remaining me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like, when you ran the WP install you didn't go into the database and change the url paths to /blog. This article should help.
http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-redirect-appwebrootblog-into-blog-wordpress-cakephp/

Comment: That's the answer that I need. That article is useful for me. Again, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I have some blog in my webroot and have added the following to my 
htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

And this is fine if I type:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/
```

However if I dont put the trailing slash (www.mydomain.com/blog) I 
get redirected to:

```
 www.mydomain.com/app/webroot/blog/
```

Comment: try %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog(.*)/?$ instead